# Firestore app keeps requests open.. I think

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm not sure what is happening exactly. I have an Angular app which connects to a firebase DB. Everything works fine, it fetches some data without problems. However, when I throttle the network to 'offline' in the devtools network tab, I suddenly see failed network requests repeatedly popping up, even though there were no pending or failed requests before toggling to 'offline'.

Upon closer inspection, I see that the request URL of these requests start with `https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?[...]` where the word 'Listen' is noticeable. I wonder if this is some kind of websocket/polling thing?

The request to get data on this page is done by the following code:
`this.db.collection(this.observationsPath).valueChanges();`;

where `this.db` is an instance of `AngularFirestore` imported from `'@angular/fire/firestore'`.

Alternatively I tried `this.db.collection(this.observationsPath).snapshotChanges();`

Why does this happen and how can I stop it? The docs don't really help, they're incredibly confusing and uninformative to things like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two listeners you shared:

```
this.db.collection(this.observationsPath).valueChanges();;

this.db.collection(this.observationsPath).snapshotChanges();
```

Both of these attach a listener to Firestore, that reads the data once initially and then keeps observing the data for changes. The latter is what causes the "hanging" call to `https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?[...]`, which is a sort'of long-polling request to be notified of such changes.

To not attach a listener you'll want to [use `get()`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/c57cef4a0d08f7df43754a30c18d707d1806cbd0/src/firestore/collection/collection.ts#L124), which gets the documents only once.

Comment: Thanks. I did find this method somewhere, but that source mentioned that it needs  `.then()` after it, which doesn't seem to work. Works perfectly without it though :)

Comment: A `get()` in the regular JavaScript SDK for Firestore returns a promise. But the AngularFire version returns an observable, just like `valueChanges` and `snapshotChanges` do. The difference is that `get()` only fires a value once, while the others continue to listen for changes and may fire multiple times.